# Am I on the right track? Feedback welcome!

Tags: united-states, investing, 401k, retirement, 457b

Here's my situation:

43 y/o, married w/ two kids under 10.

I'm in a defined benefit program and I have a formula where I can retire at 60 with 2% of my highest salary times the number of service years I accrued. By then it would be like 32 years. Could/should be pushing $200k/year salary at that point.

Also have access to 2 retirement accounts, a 457b and a 401k. I'm now maxed out in the 457b (at least the monthly amount that over 12 months will equate to the max) and I'm about halfway there on the 401k. So potentially I'll be able to save 38k annually pretax.

My wife is maxed out in her 401k AND her employer doubles her contribution up to 5%. So she essentially gets another 10% of her salary into retirement gratis.

We have about a 4-5 month emergency fund, along with some cash savings and investments that may add up to 100k. We own our house with about $450k in equity. 2 kids, 11 and 8 - we have small college savings accounts for each.

I got a late start on retirement stuff, but hopefully on the right track. Thoughts?

Long term goal would be to retire when I can and reenter the private sector to try to capitalize on my earning years...

Comment: You haven't mentioned any term life insurance that you and your wife might have.  This shouldn't be expensive at your age and is very important at least through the time that your kids are through college.   You haven't mentioned Roth IRA contributions (it sounds like you're above the threshold for deductibility of regular IRA contributions, but Roth might still be possible.)  Another obvious question is whether your emergency fund is in a high yield savings account?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I have a $750k term life insurance for myself, it's a little high due to a health condition I have, but not outrageous.  My wife has somewhere in the range of $500k I think.

I admit ignorance when it comes to Roth IRA...We have the three 401k/527b accounts, but not an IRA or Roth IRA.

And yes, the emergency fund is in a savings account.  Don't think it's terribly high yield.

Comment: An HYSA should be giving you 1.9 to 2.0% these days.  Your retail bank is probably only paying 0.1% interest or less.  2% interest on $50K is $1,000 per year- it's worth it to take an hour to set up an HYSA.

Comment: Good to know.  We have an Ally online savings account, so I guess it's right at 1.9%.   Thanks for the tip.

Comment: My only worry would be that the DB pension might go away some time in the next 30 years.

Comment: What are your retirement/savings accounts invested in? If they're not earning at least 7-10% per year it might be wise to switch them over to index funds.

Comment: RonJohn, you and me both.  It's not in any existential danger at the moment, but it's seen better times.  The trend is definitely that the participants and employers are being asked to contribute more, but it's still alive and kicking.

Comment: Dugan, we're both in targeted sunset date funds.  I think they've been doing OK, but can't say for sure it's the 7-10% range.  Will check - thank you.

Comment: Do you plan to send your kids to private high school or public?  What kind of account are you using for their college savings?

Comment: @jayinla [here's an article](https://financiallysimple.com/target-date-mutual-funds-stink/) about why target date mutual funds aren't a great choice. In general you'll be better off designing a savings plan yourself using a balance of total stock market and total bond market index funds.

Comment: Charles Fox - currently they're in catholic school.  Not sure about HS yet, but private/public both possible.  My wife works at a big university where they offer "tuition remission."  She has 4 more years before that benefit vests.  If the kids can get in, tuition will be waived.  Fees, room, board, books, etc. still out of pocket.  We have funds in Vanguard 529 plans.

Comment: Thanks, Dugan.  I will look into that option.  Like I said, this kind of stuff does not come naturally, so will need to do that research.

Hoping that our plan is basically on the right track, with a few tweaks like you suggested...

Comment: One comment - estimating your future earnings in 20 years has a huuuge '?' around it; make sure you aren't relying on that, and also don't cloud the idea of leaving for somewhere better and taking your currently accrued pension with you, if something else arises that would give you overall better quality of life. You run the risk of getting mentally trapped by 'golden handcuffs', and that could make you miserable for much of the next 2 decades, money aside.

Comment: Thanks, Bacon.  Yes, it's certainly not a sure thing.  However, I am in civil service and have good job protection, I'm in a senior position, and I actually like my work and employer.   So we'll say, barring any huge change, I could probably remain here until then without much trouble.  It's a worst case salary scenario.

But point well taken about not closing off to other positions, provided I can keep my pension plan.